# Meteor {{#each}} loop not working

Tags: meteor, each

In my HTML file, I have a #each loop like this:

```
{{#each messages}}
    {{> chat_message}}
{{/each}}
```

In my helper class I am calling a method to retrieve chat messages from the Chats collection:

```
    Template.chat_page.helpers({
    messages:function(){
        if(!Meteor.user()){
                    alert("Please log in to chat with someone");
                    return;
        }
        else{   
            var chatId = Meteor.call("startChat",Session.get("otherUserId"),function(err,res){
            if(err){
                console.log("callback failed");
                return;
            }

                Session.set("chatId", res._id);
                var arrayLength = res.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                    console.log("Message "+ i +"is " + res.message[i].text);

                }
                return res.messages;
            });
          }
     }
});
```

I can't seem to figure out why the #each loop is not showing any of the message texts returned from the helper? The text in the message array doesn't print to console either. The Session variable "chatId" does get set. So my method seems to be working and returning the entire object in "res". Any pointers?

Comment: Is the method server or client side? can you paste the method code?

Answer (score 0):

If your method is running on the server side, then it cannot set the Session variable (client-only). If the method is running on the client, it seems like it's not finding any results to your query (have you subscribed to the collection being queried?).
If the method is run on the server, then chatId will immediately return undefined on the client.

Comment: The method is running on the server side. So the callback function does work and I get a chatId back.

Answer (score 0):

Your meteor method calls to server are asynchronous meaning callback function will run later, so you can use a session variable to update the UI like this

```js
Template.chat_page.onCreated(function () {
    var template = this;
    template.autorun(function () {
        Session.setDefault("messages-" + Session.get("otherUserId"), []);
        if(!Meteor.user()){
            alert("Please log in to chat with someone");
            return;
        } else {   
            var chatId = Meteor.call("startChat", Session.get("otherUserId"),function(err,res){
            if(err){
                console.log("callback failed");
                return;
            }

                Session.set("chatId", res._id);
                var arrayLength = res.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                    console.log("Message "+ i +"is " + res.message[i].text);

                }
                Session.set("messages-" + Session.get("otherUserId"), res.messages);
            });
          }
    }); 
});

Template.chat_page.helpers({
    messages: function() {
        var otherUserId = Session.get("otherUserId");
        return otherUserId ? Session.get("messages-" + otherUserId) : [];
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! With this route I get an error - 'Uncaught Error: {{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey values.' Which is interesting because res.messages should be an array...

Comment: @achatter Sorry I have a mistake in the last line. I used `Session.set` instead of `Session.get`. I am correcting it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return directly method response to html in helper because meteor methods call its methods asynchronously.

1. You can save the response in a reactive var or session. I prefer reactive var if you don't want response as globally.
2. You can also use simple:reactive-method package that will be do you most of jobs.
   For more info visit [here](https://github.com/stubailo/meteor-reactive-method)